# PHP Parse error syntax error

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in your code on line 100

```
$clicks = each( $array )[1];
```

is this the correct syntax? (apologies for the noob question)

```
$clicks = each( $array [1]);
```

From section:

```
$array = array_count_values( $array );
        unset( $array[''] );
        do
        {
            $clicks = each( $array )[1];
            $id = each( $array )[0];
            if ( each( $array ) )
            {
            }
```

Comment: Which one throws an error, which done does not?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Array dereferencing was introduced in 5.4.... but `$clicks = each( $array )[1];` and `$clicks = each( $array [1]);` would achieve totally different things. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Well `$clicks = each( $array )[1];` is throwing the error, so I assume that would never be correct. But I'm using 5.2. If I comment out that line, the following line causes the error, so it has to be that the brackets are exposed, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of PHP that's fine, for backward compatibility, I recommend something like:

```
$clicks = each($array); $click = $clicks[1];
```

Now use `$click` instead of `$clicks`, in your code below.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better to use a foreach ($array as $key=>$val){ // do your logic here)} for array traversal, or if you want to use each's return, store it in a separate variable first, then reference the key you want.

ie:

```
$eachResult = each($array);
$clicks=$eachResult[1];
$id=$eachResult[0];
...
```

The ability to use [ ] to reference an array key of a function returning an array was only added in a very recent version of php. (5.4 I believe).

edit: Yep, 5.4: "Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0]."

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php